# c++ decltype how to use to simplify variable definition

Tags: c++, c++11

Say, I have this piece of code, in one of my classes, that defines

- A map of key and another map
- The second map is another key and a function handler
- The function hander is a signature that takes 2 params

Right now, the signature to define the variable looks incredible.

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string,
    std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<HTTPRequest>,
        std::shared_ptr<HTTPResponse>)>>> routeFunctions_;
```

I recently came to know about decltype, but unable to use this correctly.

```
decltype(x) routeFunctions_;  // What should be there in the place of x ?
```

Comment: Why not use type-aliases? Using either `typedef` or `using`? Like for example `using request_ptr = std::shared_ptr<HTTPRequest>;`. Then combine these type-aliases into broader and broader type-aliases so all you need is e.g. `route_type routeFunctions_;` You don't need (or should use) `decltype` here at all.

Comment: `x` would be an expression that has a result of the required type or the name of another variable of the required type.   Bear in mind that, if the expression yields a reference, so does `decltype`.

Comment: I think, I should go with this suggestion.  Moreover, decltype() seems to be useful, only when there is an assignment.  I may be wrong, as I am still exploring these new features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use `typedef` to this type, if you often declare variables of it.
- Use `auto` or `decltype`, if you want to return value of this type from a function.
- Use `decltype`, if you want to get type of structure/class member.

Look at this articles:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype

http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-auto-decltype-return-value-after-function.html

Your choice in this case is a `typedef`:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string,
std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<HTTPRequest>,
std::shared_ptr<HTTPResponse>)>>> RouteFunctionsContainer;

RouteFunctionsContainer routeFunctions_;
```

Answer (score 0):

You put a variable name in there that is the same type as what you want your new variable to be.

```
int x = 3;
decltype(x) y = 5; // y is an int because x is an int
```

You can pretend like the type of the variable is syntactically substituted for the decltype in the source code.

live: https://godbolt.org/g/6uzoJH

Comment: Is decltype(..) useful, only when I have a variable being assigned?  What about the case (such as mine), where there is no assignment, but just declaration..?

Comment: @Mupparthy - You have to find something that already has the right type. If this is the first use of such a map, `decltype` cannot help you.